# Hot to pass ENV to image parent from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to use some already existing image from docker hub and change many options (env variables) that are available. Locally I can set them via `docker run` command in docker-compose:

```
services:
  converter:
    image: some/image
    environment:
      - SOME_OPTION=111
```

And it works.

But on production I'm not using docker-compose. I need that env variables to be permament and ready to use in multiple projects, without manually filling env. So I decided to simply create own Dockerfile from it:

```
ENV SOME_OPTION=111
FROM some/image
```

But it's wrong because according to IDE and documentation ENV cannot be set before FROM. But when I do

```
FROM some/image
ENV SOME_OPTION=111
```

My setting is ignored by parent image.

How to handle this without passing env in commandline or using docker-compose?

## Edit:

I tried to avoid using specific images in this example because I tough it's universl docker question, not some package issue. Anyway, real example here like requested in comments:

Image is `jlesage/docker-handbrake`
It has many options listed here: https://github.com/jlesage/docker-handbrake for example `AUTOMATED_CONVERSION_PRESET`
I can change it in `docker-compose.yml` just fine. Finally I will change like 10 options and I do not want to set this in `.env` because these options should not be changed and I want to use it in other projects too with exact same video options. So I want to have separate image that will make Handbrake to work exactly like I want. I though it's what Docker is created for and it will be easy...
But when I set it in ENV in dockerfile it is just ignored, Handbreake runs with default options. It's because I'm setting this ENV after this program runs, but how to do this before then?

Comment: When you say "ignored by parent image" can you give an example?  If you're not launching the container with Compose in the production environment, how are you launching them?  There are some Docker options that are all but unavoidable (`docker run -d`, `-p`, `--net`) and you could also provide environment variables with a `docker run -e` option; building an image here doesn't seem like a typical practice.

Comment: @DavidMaze I updated question with details about real image. About "how are you launching them". I'm not doing this yet - maybe I will use separate docker-compose for prod, or by docker command, or Kubernetes - I'm not here yet with learining.. For now I'm testing this with docker-compose by removing `environment` section from it and setting this as `ENV` in Dockerfile. Because on production I should just run it and it should work out of the box, without setting multiple ENVs first..

Comment: Hello @norr i have a similar use case, do you by any chance remember if you were able to do this or if you found another way to do something similar ?

Comment: @RabbitG sorry I do not remember :/

Answer (score -2):

You don't modify the parent image, it should be treated as immutable unless you own that image. Instead you build and deploy your own image based off the parent image. So you have:

```
FROM some/image
ENV SOME_OPTION=111
```

Build it with:

```sh
docker build -t my/image .
docker push my/image
```

And then you deploy `my/image` instead of `some/image`. Note that `my/image` should point to a registry/repository where you have access to push images.

If you have built a new image with the variables set, but don't see them applying, then several possibilities come to mind:

- You may not be running your new image. You need to update the image references to point to the image you created with these settings, instead of the upstream image.
- You may be overriding the setting at runtime. The value of the ENV is the default if it is not set by the compose file, docker run, kubernetes manifest, etc. So double check how you run the image.
- The variable may be ignored by the image scripts. E.g. many images only apply variables on the first run to initialize the volume, and after that only use the settings or data in the volume.

As some initial debugging, I would run the image with a shell (like `/bin/sh`) and check the environment to see that the variable is set.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not actually what I was asking. I know how to build or push image, i has nothing to do with issue. My example code does not work, because ENV is ignored by parent image. If I understand correctly, it happens because app in it starts BEFORE next layer (ENV). So I need to set ENV before FROM but it's against docker docs for some reason.

Comment: The env is ignored by the parent image because you never change the parent image. You add the env to the image you are building. If I could arbitrarily change the parent image, I would add a Bitcoin miner to the official Alpine image that everyone uses, but that's not how any of this works.